# How can I write text from an HTML snippet to a text file with line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div>` that receives messages from users in the format of, '[time][username]: *message here*.

I'm attempting to download the contents of this div to a text file. What I've done works, but, the contents of the download looks like, "`<p><i>19:27:05</i> <strong>Bob</strong>: hey</p>`". It also displays another div inside it.

How can I ignore these <> tags in the download, and have each individual message appear on a line by itself, similar to how they appear when I render the HTML itself?

*Eg:*

*19:27:05* **Bob**: hey

*19:30:00* **Peter**: how are you?

script.js:

```
var downClick = document.getElementById('download');

downClick.addEventListener('click', function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'chat','text/html');
})

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'chat history.txt';
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chat" class="chat">
   <div class="istyping" id="istyping"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking the text inside an element, but you are selecting the HTML.

To obtain just the text inside an element and all of its descendants, use [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

From the MDC web docs:

> The innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

Comment: Changing `var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;` to `var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerText;` worked, thanks.